# Is it a good practice to modify the request body in a middleware?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, request, middleware

Hello guys I have a question about middlewares.

I have an API with two constraints:

- Checking if the access token is valid
- Checking if the user is admin

I have to check if the access token is valid in the whole api but I don't have to check if the user is admin everywhere. So the problem is that I created two middlewares, one for the token validation and one for the role of the user. But I repeat a lot of action in these two middleware like getting the token from the header of the request...

I wanted to know if I can pass the access token from the first middleware to the second one, using the request body (so modify the request). Is it a good practice to modify the request in a middleware? Because I thought the middleware was only there to check if we can access to the next step.

Thanks to everyone who will answer my question! And sorry if the post already exists. I've tried my best to search about it before, but that's a really subjective question.

Comment: Middleware modifies things all the time.

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton, thanks for your answer! Then that's okay if I modify the request...